# Mono VLC API for Linux

Tags: c#, linux, video, mono, libvlc

Basically i am trying to build a mono video player that uses VLC and is able to run on windows and linux.  I have found a number of good libraries in c# that work on mono for talking to the VLC API dll's but those dll's don't exist on linux and looking at the libraries code it looks like they may only work on windows anyway.

Are there any c#, mono wrappers for the VLC dll on linux?  At the minute i am focusing on VLC as i need the Hi10 support and as far as i know VLC is the old cross platform player with that and with an API interface.  That said i am open to ideas.

Comment: After further research it seems MPlayer maybe a better cross platform match and already has c# wrappers that work in mono and dotnet on linux and windows and should work on mac. API is much easier and it can play everything VLC can. Will test and make it the answer if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPlayer seems to be a much better match and the c# wrapper [MPLayerControl Lib](https://github.com/majorsilence/MPlayerControl) is an excellent wrapper. Strongly recommend MPlayer for anyone trying something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Tried to use https://github.com/majorsilence/MPlayerControl and it works fine when I use Winforms. However I did not manage to get the GTK# example up and running... It opens a new Mplayer window instead of being embedded in the application

Comment: I did not try the GTK# for windows.  If i remember correctly i went with the winforms version and that seems to work everywhere though i had a few performance issues on a Mac it was fine on linux and windows

Comment: Just looking at this control, which as of August 2020 it looks like there is a recent updat, but I cannot get a C# winforms example running, any new examples out there that work and anyone still using this? (appreciating this is a very old post)